# Java button, switch to another frame, closing current frame and running a method in another class

Tags: java

I have tried creating a button "Menu", and on click it closed the frame that it's on, open a class StartWindow, after that it would use a method "Menu", without running method "Welcome". But in stead it doesn't close the frame, but also runs just the class, which at first runs only method "Welcome"

Button:

```
menu.setBounds(1, 1, 65, 65);
        menu.setFocusable(false);
        menu.setText("Menu");
        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent j) {
                if(j.getSource() == menu) {
                    StartWindow menu = new StartWindow();
                    frame.dispose();
                    menu.Menu(frame);

                    
                }
            }
        });
```

Constructor

StartWindow(){
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

```
    frame.setSize(420, 420);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    
    Welcome(frame);
    
}
```

````
Method:
```Java
    public void Menu(JFrame frame){
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        JTextField text1= new JTextField();
        JTextField text2= new JTextField();
        JButton button1= new JButton();
        JButton button2= new JButton();
        
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setSize(420, 420);
        panel1.setBackground(new Color(212, 190, 190));
        
        text1.setText("With friends");
        text1.setBackground(new Color(212, 190, 190));
        text1.setBounds(140, 60, 65, 40);
        text1.setBorder(null);
        text1.setFocusable(false);
        text1.setEditable(false);
        
        text2.setText("With AI");
        text2.setBackground(new Color(212, 190, 190));
        text2.setBounds(140, 132, 65, 40);
        text2.setBorder(null);
        text2.setEditable(false);
        text2.setFocusable(false);
        
        //With friend
        button1.setBounds(140, 100, 85, 32);
        button1.setBackground(new Color(212, 190, 190));
        button1.setFocusable(false);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                if(a.getSource() == button1) {
                    frame.dispose();
                    new TTT_1();
                }
            
            }
            
        });
        button1.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));
        button1.setText("1 VS 1");
        
        //AI
        button2.setBounds(140, 172, 75, 32);
        button2.setBackground(new Color(212, 190, 190));
        button2.setFocusable(false);
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {
                if(b.getSource() == button2) {
                    frame.dispose();
                    new TTT_2();
                }
                
            }
            
        });
        button2.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));
        button2.setText("AI");
        
        panel1.add(text1);
        panel1.add(text2);
        panel1.add(button1);
        panel1.add(button2);    
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
````

I had a few theories on what is wrong, one of them is the constructor that it can be redesigned and it will solve my problem, another was that there is something wrong in the button.

Comment: So you want a login/welcome window and then after that, just get on with using the app?

Comment: yes, kind of, if you want to look at the full code i can share the link for it

Comment: I would personally use a `CardLayout` for this: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout

Comment: My idea was that, when a person opens the app(game) firstly he sees is the welcome panel, and after he presses continue button, they would never actually see this panel again until they exited out of the app(game) and opened it again. Which means when a person from a game wants to go back, by pressing the button which should open class and run the method, and the method that it needs to be ran is this one(the on is above)

Comment: Yes, that's what me example does

Comment: Can you please upload the full code